# "Application not installed" for Live Wallpaper, on some phones

Tags: android

I made a Live Wallpaper for a client, and they've had a report that a friend with a Galaxy S (running 2.2, rooted) is getting "Application not installed" when they try to install.

I've not had this myself on the devices/emulator I have, neither did my client. I can only imagine it is to do with AndroidManifest.xml

Here it is:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="World Rugby NZ 2011 LIVE Wallpaper">

    <service
        android:label="World Rugby NZ 2011"
        android:name=".RugbyWallpaper"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" /> 
    </service>

</application>

<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

I have this in /res/xml/wallpaper.xml

```
<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:thumbnail="@drawable/icon"
/>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Is this the first version of the wallpaper on your friend's phone?

Comment: @Sticky where you able to solve this ?? I have the same problem . Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit late for an answer but perhaps it helps someone:

You have to add the `Activity` of your settings to the Android manifest

```xml
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="World Rugby NZ 2011 LIVE    Wallpaper">

  <service
   .
   .
   .>
  </service>
 <activity
        android:name=".WhateverYourSettingsAreCalled"
        android:label="@string/title_wall_settings" 
        android:exported="true" >
  </activity>
```